URL not included in the external fetch backend permissions: /wiki/api/v2/pages/
I try run, any of these examples on Confluence and I get a permissions-related error message.
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/dd23-forge-confluence/src/main/

const fetchPage = async (contentId) => {

  // Call the Get Page by ID API as the user displaying the app.  Confluence API V2
  // https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v2/api-group-page/#api-pages-id-get
  const response = await api.asUser().requestConfluence(route`/wiki/api/v2/pages/${contentId}`, {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
});

Do I need add something in manifest.yml file?

Yes. You'll need to add the egress traffic URL to manifest.yml.
If you go to go.atlassian.com/forge-egress then you should find the relevant documentation.
Basically, if your forge app is sending traffic to www.example.com using fetch then your manifest should contain something like this.
permissions:
  external:
    fetch:
      backend:
        - '*.example.com'

I'd recommend that you use forge remotes though since it the newer syntax. And, should look like this.
permissions:
external:
  fetch:
    backend:
      - remote: remote-backend
remotes:
- key: remote-backend
  baseUrl: "https://www.example.com"
  operations:
      - fetch

Note that "forge remotes" doesn't support globbing in the URL.

Even though it's a Confluence API request?

It doesn't work for me. I'm following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pA05Z9-fq2I
The recording does not mention that you need to add access to an external backend.
